# Android scrollable screen for android charts

Tags: android, xml, mpandroidchart, android-scrollbar

There must be questions about this issue, but none of the ones I found related solved my problem. So.

I have the following scenario, I want a screen that I can scroll down over the multiples charts I will have. [Like this image represents here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDpUA.png)

For now, with the code below, [I am getting this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHbmH.png).

So, what is going on is that both charts are on each other, and I do not know why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/secondLayout">

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pieChart" />

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/barChart"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using the MPAndroidchart library.

Thanks.

Comment: What you have is ok to scroll from top to bottom except I did not understand your question

Comment: @NollyJ sorry, I edited the description and added an image relating my problem with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modify version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout">          


        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/pieChart" />

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/barChart"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pieChart"              
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Nolly J, thank you for helping me. I used your solution, but changed the layout_width to **fill_parent** and layout_height to some arbitrary value, like 500px, of both charts. It worked like a charm. I know hardcoded value is not good, but how can I set the height size in Density-independent pixel (dp), or some kind of size that will resize in other phones screens? Thanks.

Comment: You can create different values folders for different screen size and inside the folders, you create a dimen folder. The add - <dimen name="height">60dp</dimen> with different values.

Answer (score 0):

the question isn't clear,what's your problem exactly?
if you mean your chart are on each other , try use LinearLayout with vertical orientetion Instead of your second RelativeLayout.

Comment: If you saw the image, the charts are on each other. Besides this, thank you for the answer, I am going to test your suggestion later.